# How do I reduce the resolution of my Flip Mino HD?

Tags: flip

My Flip Mino HD automatically takes all video in HD.  But I would like to lower the resolution.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the Flip devices only support one resolution. The Mino HD can only capture video at 1280x720.

You can however [transcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcode) the video once its captured to a different resolution using a [video transcoder](http://www.google.com/search?q=video+transcoder).